# Problem with building kernel for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel

I am trying to build a kernel on Ubuntu 22.04 using instructions from [phoenixnap.com](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/build-linux-kernel). The kernel fails with these errors:

```
root@ko-System-Product-Name:/home/ko/Downloads/linux-4.9.337# make

ld: lib/lib.a(string.o): in function `stpcpy':
/home/ko/Downloads/linux-4.9.337/lib/string.c:258: undefined reference to `__ubsan_handle_nonnull_return_v1'
make: *** [Makefile:1017: vmlinux] Error 1
```

Comment: When I try to install the card,SkyStar 2 eXpress HD I lose the graphics card driver      That's why I decided to install another kernel in which the card works, or is there another solution?         https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/TechniSat_SkyStar_2_eXpress_HD/